# SQL - Add 10% to an Outputted Value

Tags: sql, magento, attributes, copy

I have the following `SQL` query below:

```
INSERT INTO ry_catalog_product_entity_decimal
(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, 290, store_id, entity_id, value
FROM ry_catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE attribute_id = 65;
```

This is to copy a Magento attribute from one column to another. "290" is the attribute that is copied from "65." I am wondering how I add 10% to the price in "65" and have this reflected in "290"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO ry_catalog_product_entity_decimal
(entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value)
SELECT entity_type_id, 290, store_id, entity_id, ((a.value * .1) + a.value) as value
FROM ry_catalog_product_entity_decimal a
WHERE attribute_id = 65;
```